# Question about "growing layers of a planar graphs"

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

Given a planar graph $G$  k nodes $S$ of $G$ construct "layers" $L_i$ for $i=0,1,...$ as follows  $L_0=S$,  having constructed layers $L_0,L_1,..,L_i$ layer $L_{i+1}$ consists of those nodes of $G 
 \backslash  (L_0 \cup L_1 \cup .. \cup L_i ) $ which have two neighbours in $L_0 \cup L_1 \cup .. \cup L_i $
Suppose that every vertex of $L_{i+1}$ has a distinct pair of two neighbours in $L_0 \cup L_1 \cup .. \cup L_i$

How large can the layer $L_i$  be?

Comment: First consider the case where $k = 2$ and you are asking how large $L_1$ can be.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  Fixed question to address this issue.

Comment: Avoiding a specific counter-example with a narrowly tailored change *rarely ever* fixes an issue. It certainly hasn't here. All you've required is that the unbounded number of nodes in $L_1$ have to have other links than just the links to the two nodes in $S$. If you want a bounded result, you need to examine *in detail* what went wrong, and figure out how to prevent it from going wrong in *all* cases, not just this one.